# check in php if a object is a instance of a class but not a instance of a subclass

Tags: php, oop, constructor

I have these classes

```
class db {
}
class el {
 public function __construct (db $db) {
 $this->db = $db;
 }
}
class a {
  public function __construct (db $db) {   
 } 
}
class b extends a {
 public function __construct ($db) {
  parent::__construct($db);
 } 
}
class c extends b {
 public function __construct ($db) {
  parent::__construct($db);
 }
}
```

If I instantiate class b everything is OK

```
new b(new el(new db ()));
```

But if I instantiate class c a got an error

```
new c(new el(new db ()));
```

> PHP Catchable fatal error:  Argument 1 passed to a::__construct() must be an instance of db, instance of el given

What should I do to solve the situation:

- Force class c constructor to call class a constructor. But how ?
- In class b constructor decide from the argument the right way to call class a constructor.
- In class b constructor decide if is directly instantiated or from the extended class c and use the right way to call class a constructor.

Comment: Why does el not extend db?

Comment: This is an example, in the real case:

db is database connection class;

el is a (generic) entity that uses db connection but does not expands it;

a is a agency entity (so extends el) ;

b is a graveyard entity (so extends agency);
c is a parlour entity (so extends agency).

Comment: If you override the constructor with entirely different types, then you simply shouldn't call the parent constructor. Obviously this can get somewhat messy, so the real answer is to keep your types simple without a lot of overloading and changing types in subclasses. You need to create a saner OO model with sound types; yours just looks like random patchwork right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `get_class($this)` in the B class constructor, you will be able to differentiate from a call to parent constructor from C or a direct call.

See : http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php, example #2.

Iansus.

Comment: Thank you, I applied your solution  in this way
class b extends a {
 public function __construct ($db) {
  //parent::__construct($db);
  if (get_class($this) == __CLASS__) {
   parent::__construct($db);
  } else {
   parent::__construct($db->db);
  }
 } 
}